# Open exploits database, with structured data (CMS name, version, etc.)

Tags: web-application, exploit

For a web security app I'm working on, I want to list all the exploits that a certain Wordpress version have. (and hopefully the same for other CMSs)

I found some (open) exploits databases that list those kind of exploits:

- [National Vulnerability Database](https://web.nvd.nist.gov)
- [CVEDetails](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/4096/Wordpress-Wordpress.html?vendor_id=2337)

Unfortunately, their exploits database is not really structured *(**EDIT**: actually the National Vulnerability Database is the perfect fit for what we wanted, check my answer below)*. CVEDetails gives exploits per application, but it's hard to get the version number from that ; Also they don't give an access to some structured database (XML, JSON, ...) or API to easily fetch the exploits. The 'National Vulnerability Database' doesn't give details about which app and version is vulnerable.

Where could I find some open (and free for commercial use) exploit databases?

Comment: You're confusing the term "exploit" with "vulnerability". A vulnerability is a flaw in a program, while an exploit is a demonstrated use of that flaw. (Also, I'd be remiss if I didn't plug my own SCAP solution which has a better API than the NVD: https://scapsync.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using the [NVD](http://nvd.nist.gov/) (National Vunlnerability Database) which is based on the [SCAP](http://scap.nist.gov/) protocol for automating the retrieval of vulnerabilities based on a [`CPE`](http://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm) id (for instance, the `CPE` id of Joomla! 7.1 beta1 would be: `cpe:/a:joomla:joomla%21:7.1:beta1`).

Their database is really extensive and gives `CVE` id and `CVSS` score for each exploit.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [CVE database](http://cve.mitre.org/) itself. They have a structured XML where you can extract all vulnerabilities you want.

Answer (score 4):

The [OSVDB](http://www.osvdb.org/) provides [an API](http://www.osvdb.org/api/about) for exactly this sort of thing.  It's free but limited to 2 queries per day for non-commercial use.  You will need to pay for a license if you want more than this.

In the past they have also provided database dumps in various formats however I'm not sure if they still do this.

---

A word on free-for-commercial-use: No matter where you get your vulnerability information from, you will probably find that if your product is at all successful you will either be contacted with a request for money or your customer's requests will suddenly be blocked.

You should plan accordingly.

Comment: Unless it's state-financed or for non-profit :-) (check my answer !)

Thanks for the link btw, I've already found OSVDB, too bad their website is a bit 'obscure' about licensing conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the only way to use thoses databases is to parse HTML result pages. cvedetails looks the better structured site for this own, but still hard to get product and version IDs

Comment: Please check my answer. The NVD database is available in XML and is actually well structured. You can easily find exploits for a given software by looking up it's CVE code. Something like this: ``cpe:a/wordpress:wordpress:3.5:beta``